# cordova-plugin-firebase working in android but not in ios

Tags: cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm developing a phonegap mobile app for ios and android and building it with phonegap cli. 
I have installed cordova-plugin-firebase for push notifications.

Following instructions in https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase

In Android:
I have downloaded google-services.json and placed it in platforms/android folder.
I'm testing the app in a device and push notifications are working.

In iOS:
I have downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist and placed it in platforms/ios/[My Project]/Resources folder.
I'm testing the app in a device but push notifications are not working.

Any help?
Thanks

EDITED

In my app.js now I have included window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission() but still is not working:

```
var app = new Framework7({
root: '#app', // App root element
...
on: {
    init: function () {
        if (Framework7.device.ios) {
            window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission();
        }
    },
},
...
});
```

Is that incorrect?

Comment: Do you add `window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission();`in iOS code ?

Comment: No I don't! I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: Keep me informed !

Comment: I have edited my post with the modification for including this code

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now it's working!

First, I had commentted in index.html this line:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Now, uncommentted, the next event handler works (before it wasn't working)

```
$$(document).on('deviceready', function () {
if (app.device.ios) {         
    window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission();
}
});
```

Now the app ask me for grant permission and if I accept push notifications works.

Thanks